# Access to child from parent tab

Tags: javascript

I try to click button on just opened page, but get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined`

```
var target = window.open("link");
target.document.body.getElementsByClassName("button class").item().click()
```

Could you please help?

Comment: well, what does window.open return? btw, window.open expects two arguments at least

Comment: new window openes, but autocomplition on target variable do not work

Comment: To be pedantic I believe that *all* window.open's parameters are optional, even `window.open()` alone is valid. However in practice it is rare to see fewer than two parameters.

Comment: What does the console show you is the value of target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what `"link"` is (at face value it is a page or servlet sibling to the main URL, but named `link`- however I suspect you are using it as a placeholder for something else) your main page may not have permission to access the document object, depending on the security policy as applied by the browser. For instance, you would see that error message normally if `link` was replaced by a URL with a different domain from that of the main page.

Comment: link is absolute(like http://google.com) and windows.open creates correct new page